# Folder with multiple xml schema file to C# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have folder with multiple subfolders containing xsd files with references other files. I tried to convert them to C# classes individually with xsd.exe, but because there are type references it is impossible. Which is the best way to convert schema folder to C# class. Best result would be one C# file with multiple classes. Schema is so large that this code file will probably contain over 50 000 rows, but it is't problem.

Comment: If you have more than one schema the main schema need an import in the root tag to the other schema :  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
It can be a filename instead of the URL

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I digged more and noticed that references is not for other files in folder.
There are references as url like xmlns:ce=myFakeUrl/basictypes
And usage is like <xs:element name="Title" type="ce:MyType"/>
And error is like "Datatype myFakeUrl/basictypes/:MyType is missing"

Comment: And <xs:import namespace="myFakeUrl/basictypes"
  schemaLocation="basictypes.xsd"/>
And this basictypes.xsd is in same file folder than schema i try to import

Comment: "is missing" may be a required property and not in the xml file when validating.  So a title is missing in the xml file and is required by the schema.  Is Title in any other xsd.  You could be using the wrong namespace "ce".  The ce gets you too a schema and the schema may not have a title type.

Comment: When i run "xsd schema1.xsd basicstypes.xsd" i avoid error and get new similar because then there are same situation in basictypes.xsd.
So it seems that i should write those all over 100 schema name in row to avoid missing type error O:
I think there are some logic in this schema folder but i am not smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: The schema are a tree structure.  Sit down with a piece of paper and draw the tree.

Comment: I get tree documentation from schema owner, and after writing down those over 40 xml files in one xsd command i get "circular reference error". It seems that xsd.exe cant handle those circular references.

Comment: I don't think you are suppose to include all the owners schema in one xml file.  Only the ones that are needed.  There are many different types of SOAP bodies.  So there may be a different body xsd that you use for a request and another for a response.  The vendor may have errors in the schema structure.  Do you have to modify the owners schema.  Usually schema has user defined sections and may need modification.  You may be using the wrong prefixes which would give duplicates.

Comment: Zip file i have contain lot of more than about 40 files, but i need over 40 because there are those object references. There are basicobject.xsd and basicobjectdata.xsd which define  content for basic object.xsd. I should maybe try to do import programmatically. XML schema i have defines dome official industry standars, so i can't modify structure myself, or schema is't valid anymore.

Comment: The schema are different layers of the tree.  So you can only include one layer of schema in each of your xml.  Add the schema using Include a few at a time until you isolate each issue and fix.

Comment: Thank you for your multiple response! I am new with xml and you helped me to understand topic. Now i believe that i'll reach my goal with this schema.